# Проверка структуры выражения в String

Tags: java, строки

Пользователь должен вводить любое выражение в виде формулы.Например a+b+c-d+f которое пользователь вводит в консоле.
Если пользователь вводит неправильную формулу то есть a+df+sdfg или +a+5+b+c//  то должно вызываться исключение что формула имеет неправильную структуру. Формула должна состоять только из букв алфавита и знаков. Цифр не должно быть и должны вводиться только маленькие буквы.

```
    String sIn  = null;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Введите формулу: ");
    sIn = in.nextLine();
    boolean flag=true;
    for (int j = 0; j < d.length(); j++) {
                 ch = d.charAt(i);
    String s = Character.toString(ch);

    if(s.matches("[a-z]")&& 
      Character.toString(d.charAt((d.length()-1))).matches("[a-z]")){

                    // .....
                }
     else new Throwable("Неправильная структура формулы");
```

здесь только проверяется первая и последняя буква алфавита. Но если пользователь вводит без знаков буквы или большие буквы то исключение не выскакивает. Спасибо.

Если сделать так:

```
            boolean bool =true;
            char ch,chfirst, chlast;

            String str="a+b-c+a";
            chfirst = sIn.charAt(0);
            chlast = sIn.charAt(sIn.length()-1);

            if(Character.toString(chfirst).matches("[a-z]")&&
               Character.toString(chlast).matches("[a-z]")){
                for (int j = 0; j < sIn.length(); j++) {
                     ch = sIn.charAt(j);
                    if(j%2==0 && Character.toString(ch).matches("[a-z]")){
                        bool = true;
                    }
                }

            } else bool = false;
            System.out.println(bool);
```

то результат получается более желаемый но все же если вводить не поотдельность буквы а вместе например aa+bb+c-r+d  то результат выдает тоже true. Как сделать так чтобы только поотдельности буквы разрешалось вводить то есть например d+b+a-c? Спасибо.

Comment: Очень интересное задание! Парсер арифметических выражений должен написать в своей жизни хоть раз любой студент. А в чём вопрос-то?

Comment: @VladD, давайте на регекспах )

Comment: @Nofate: Слишком просто! :-) Да и в ideone отлаживать неудобно.

Comment: вопрос как это сделать попроще

Comment: сделал изменение но все равно не совсем желаемый результат

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Статья про регулярные выражения.](http://www.quizful.net/post/Java-RegExp)
Воспользуйся методом matcher и будет тебе счастье.
По сути - у тебя будет примерно такой код:

```
package stackowerflowstring;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class StackOwerflowString {

    public static String str = "";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        str = "a";        
        System.out.println(str + " " + test(str)); //true  
        str = "a+b";        
        System.out.println(str + " " + test(str)); //true 
        str = "a-b";        
        System.out.println(str + " " + test(str)); //true 
        str = "a*b";        
        System.out.println(str + " " + test(str)); //true 
        str = "a/b";        
        System.out.println(str + " " + test(str)); //true 
        str = "a+b-";        
        System.out.println(str + " " + test(str)); 
        str = "a+bb";        
        System.out.println(str + " " + test(str)); 
        str = "a+D";        
        System.out.println(str + " " + test(str));
        str = "a+r-b";        
        System.out.println(str + " " + test(str)); //true 
    }

    public static boolean test(String testString){  
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(
                //начало формулы, может быть одна буква 
                "^[a-z]"
                //регулярное выражение вида +а, неограниченное кол-во раз
              + "([+|\\-|*|/][a-z])*"

        );
        Matcher m = p.matcher(testString);  
        return m.matches();  
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо большое! только для того чтобы не разрешалось1 букву я добавил вместо {1,}$  вместо *

Comment: Можно было просто + поставить вместо звезды. Это от одного включительно

Comment: а как быть если в выражении содержатся скобки например  d+(b+a)*c? Можно эту проверку тоже с regex сделать?

Comment: Есть такой способ - обратная польская запись. https://habrahabr.ru/post/100869/ - тут описано, для затравки пойдет. А так - нужен парсер, который просто переписывает строку в обратной польской записи.

Comment: пример со скобками чуть позже постараюсь написать, на работу пора)

Answer (score 1):

Главный класс, для ввода с консоли я думаю понятно как модифицировать, :

```
package consolejava;
public class consolejava{
   public static void main(String[] args) {       
      String str = "QUOTE+QUOTE+a+(a+d+(s+d))";      
      if(str.contains("("))
         System.out.println(str + " " +  CheckRegular.test(checkString.CheckStr(str)));
      else System.out.println(str + " " + CheckRegular.test(str)); 
   }
}
```

Класс для проверки верности выражения, небольшая модификация ранее описанного алгоритма:

```
package consolejava;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
public class CheckRegular {    
    private static String str = "";
    public static boolean test(String testString){  
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(
                //начало формулы, может быть одна буква или ключевое слово, обозначающее выражение в скобках 
                "^([a-z]|QUOTE)"
                //регулярное выражение вида +а, неограниченное кол-во раз
              + "([+|\\-|*|/]([a-z]|QUOTE))*"
        );
        Matcher m = p.matcher(testString);  
        return m.matches();  
    }
}
```

Класс для поиска выражений в скобках:

```
package consolejava;
public class checkString {    
    private static String stringInQuote = "";
    private static Integer indexClose = 0, indexOpen = 0;
    private static boolean FLAG = false;   
    public static String CheckStr (String s)
    {
        //ищем первую закрывающую скобку
        indexClose = s.indexOf(")");
        if(indexClose.equals(-1))return "ERROR";
        //ищем открывающую скобку для нее       
        indexOpen = s.lastIndexOf("(", indexClose);
         if(indexOpen.equals(-1))return "ERROR";
        //вытаскиваем строку и проверяем ее на правильность
        stringInQuote = s.substring(indexOpen + 1, indexClose);        
        FLAG = CheckRegular.test(stringInQuote);
        //если правильно, заменим выражение в скобках ключевым словом
        if(FLAG) stringInQuote = s.substring(0, indexOpen) + "QUOTE" + s.substring(indexClose + 1);
        //иначе возвращаем значение, которое вызовет ошибку(ключевое слово ошибки)
        else return "ERROR";        
        //если в строке еще есть скобки, рекурсивно обработаем строку
        if(stringInQuote.contains(")"))stringInQuote = CheckStr(stringInQuote);
        //иначе вернем строку
        return stringInQuote; 
    }    
}
```